# Problem, angle between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to calculate the angle between two vectors.
As I understand, the dot product of two vectors is equal to the angle.
What I cant grasp is this:

Given a vector $A$ and $B$ where $A = \left(5,7\right)$ and $B = \left(5,7\right)$

How can the dot product become $74$ ?
Using this site to check my results http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vector-calculator.html

Comment: The dot product of two vectors depend on the angle, alright. But it's not _equal_ to the angle. It is equal to the _cosine_ of the angle, multiplied by the length of each of the two vectors. If the angle is $0$, the cosine is $1$, and so the result is just the product of the two vector's lengths.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is $$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}=||\mathbf{u}||\ ||\mathbf{v}|| \cos\theta.$$

We have $||(5,7)||=\sqrt{5^2+7^7}=\sqrt{74}$, and so, using the above formula, we have $$\cos\theta=\frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{||\mathbf{u}||\ ||\mathbf{v}||}=\frac{74}{\sqrt{74}\sqrt{74}}=1,$$ which implies $\theta=0$ (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

Well, for vectors $a,b$, you know that $a \cdot b = |a|\cdot |b| \cdot \cos(\theta)$.

Let's compute the dot product: $a \cdot b = 5^2 + 7^2 = 74$.

Then let's compute the Euclidian norms: note that $a=b$, so we only have to compute one. $|a| = \sqrt{5^2 + 7^2} = \sqrt{74}$.

Then we have $74 = \sqrt{74}\sqrt{74} \cos(\theta)$, implying $74 = 74 \cos(\theta)$, so $\cos(\theta) = 1$, which implies that $\theta = 0$.

Comment: I think it is better to use norm $||.||$ instead of $|.|$ for vectors

Comment: @Belgi that's just my preferred notation --- I like to use as few symbols as possible to prevent confusion, and I think my use of $|x|$ for norm is reasonably clear in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$(5,7)(5,7)=25+49=74$$
Those vectors  $A=B$. Therefore angle = 0